# Updating Magento 1.9.3.9 to 1.9.4.1

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-connect, magento-1.9.4.1, magento-1.9.3.9

I need to update my magento platform from 1.9.3.9 to 1.9.4.1. I know that is possible to do it with Magento connect but I see that it isn't safety.

Are there any other ways to update Magento securely?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't edited any core files you should be good. The alternative to Magento Connect is download the files and overwriting them in your root directory.

Comment: Only core files or other folders yes?

Answer (score 0):

I used Softaculous in Cpanel with no problems